# Redirect http port to nodePort

Tags: kubernetes, iptables

I have a kubernetes 1.5 cluster (with flannel network) and with server port range from 50000 - 55000. What I would like to do is to redirect traffic from VIP:80 to NODE_IP:55000.

- **VIP**: 10.66.122.115
- **NODE_IP**: 10.66.122.116 (both IP addresses are
  assigned to same host, but VIP can move if host is down)

iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dst 10.66.122.115 \
     --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.66.122.116:55000
```

Yet, it doesn't work. If I run simple http server on some other port and enter corresponding rule iptables then it works, but same rule for kubernetes does not work. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No, we gave up and took ingress.

Answer (score -2):

You can try ingress.. if there is an external traffic terminating on your k8s cluster, your ingress rules will direct it to a service and a port (like node port etc)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
```